# Connecting Server-Side Java to Front-End Javascript for iOS App

Tags: java, javascript, ios, sencha-touch-2, server-side

I am writing a web app for iOS using Sencha Touch 2.0 and am using Javascript primarily on the front end however I plan on using Sencha to "package" the app into what is nearly a native app.

I need to access java code on a server - some functions are used to query a database, another is used to run a barcode scanner.  For the carcode scanner, I also need to pass the server a picture taken from the iOS Library.

I am very new to both of these languages and need specific instruction at a basic level on how to connect the databases and then run these java functions, send the picture to the database, and return results (alphanumerics) to the javascript.  Thank you much!

Comment: What languages ​​do you work so far?

Comment: Javascript is the language used with the Sencha framework for the front-end.  We have java projects that we have on a server and need to access those java projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for java to database, you can look into using JDBC, JPA or ORM like Hibernate.  You don't necessarily need to store the graphic in the database - you can save it on the file system and simply point to it via the database.  The java server can communicate to the javascript UI/front end via AJAX (using JSON format) - you could look into using something like socket.io (uses web sockets and falls back on flash sockets/long polling)
From the UI - you can make getJSON calls as well to call your Java code on the server.

Sample call using JQuery (you do not need to use Jquery - this is just for reference).  In this case, the form submit (can be any other action) makes a post call to "login" on the server side - the serialized array (JSON format) can be parsed on the server side.  This is strictly for reference - you can make a JSON call from any client and handle it on the server (register a success callback which will get invoked when the server responds with a message).

```
var v = jQuery("#login").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
var data =  $.toJSON(jQuery('#login').serializeArray()); {
var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "login",
contentType: "application/json",
data: data,
timeout: 5000,
  success: function(data) {
if ($.parseJSON(data).indexOf("Invalid") == -1) {
jQuery('#displayResponse').html($.parseJSON(data));
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?  I'm looking into AJAX now.  I can use that to establish the connection and instantiate the java programs, correct?  I found some javascript code to send images to a server which can also be run in the AJAX.  I can also pass the file name with picture and create a folder to save all files to.  I can then pass that file name as an input to the java barcode decoder program.  So where does the socket.io come into play?  Thanks!

Comment: with AJAX - you can make a call from javascripp running on the client - send the request in JSON format to the server (either calling a JSP/Servlet or calling a POJO).  On the server (running java), if sending a message in JSON format, you can parse the JSON, run the operation on the database (CRUD) & respond with data in JSON format to the client (on the client side, the callback registered earlier, when you sent the initial JSON, will get invoked - you can parse the JSON and display on the UI).  hope it helps

Comment: you don't need socket.io if you don't need web sockets - just straight AJAX is good

Comment: Can you write all that code for me and I'll fill in the necessary blanks like the name of my server?

Comment: ...even just some snippets of code on what you mean would help because i am totally lost as to where to go with this.